# Indexing, Strings, Lists

Tags: jython

Go through the list of fruits and print each one in the string “I added this  to our produce”. The parameter is "a list of crop names (strings) and there is no return value.

Test Case

```
crops = [‘apple’, ‘orange’, ‘banana’, ‘strawberry’]
daysWork(crops)

I added this apple to our produce
I added this orange to our produce
I added this banana to our produce
I added this strawberry to our produce
```

My Code:

```
def daysWork(crops):
  for crop in crops:
    produce = crops[n]
  print 'I added this ' + str(produce) + ' to our produce'
```

The error I get is "The error was:n Name not found globally."

Is n not indexing the list at each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's for <s>loop</s> statement is actually a for-each statement, [which differs from what you're used to in C or Java.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)  `for crop in crops` references each element in `crops` with the variable `crop`.

What you want instead is:

```
for crop in crops:
    produce = crop
```